# Polymer and Jquery selector

Tags: jquery, dom, polymer, shadow-dom

I have the following code using Polymer:

```
<polymer-element name="new-post-page">
    <template>
        <div id="trumbowyg-demo"></div>
    </template>
    <script>
        Polymer("new-post-page", 
        {
        });
    </script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>window.jQuery</script>
    <script src="../../bower_components/trumbowyg/dist/trumbowyg.min.js"></script>
    <script>$('#trumbowyg-demo').trumbowyg();</script>
</polymer-element>
```

As you can see I use the Jquery selector in order to show the WYSIWYG editor. Unfortunalety it does not happen anything. It works outside the polymer element definition which is why I think this has something to do with the issue.

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`trumbowyg-demo` is not inside the DOM, it's only inside the *shadow DOM* of your element. You can use the standard CSS selector or the Polymer `$` map to get your element and then convert it to a jQuery object:

```
$(this.$.trumbowyg-demo).trumbowyg()
```

You need to be in a Polymer method to access the `this` variable. You should move your code to a domReady method.

There is probably a jQuery syntax to use the selector from the shadow DOM too (something like $(this.shadowDOM).find('#trumbowyg-demo')), but I don't know the exact syntax.

Answer (score 3):

I got it working like that:

```
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
<script href="../bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>

<dom-module id="my-red-frame">
    <template>
        <div class="redbox">
            <content></content>
        </div>
    </template>

    <script>
        Polymer({
            is: "my-red-frame",
            ready: function () {
                // Changing background color this way just to provide an example
                $(this).find(".redbox").css("background-color", "red");
            }
        });
    </script>

</dom-module>
```

Answer (score 0):

`$('#trumbowyg-demo').trumbowyg()` you need the `#` to select by `id`.

Comment: You are right, but however in my code it is correct. Strange copy & paste error.